Can I export app usage data(Device Activity framework) to an external database
I want to make an app purely for academia to get the app usage data which includes timestamps of app usage and I want to store this data in a MySQL database for analysis purposes. From what I have read online, I don't get access to the raw data instead I can only see the data in Views. Is there any way I can export this data outside the app? Is it even possible?

It is not possible to export device activity.  This is a deliberate, privacy-preserving design decision by Apple.
Device Activity Report

When you create a report, the system asks your app’s device activity report extension to provide a View representing the user’s device activity. To protect the user’s privacy, your extension runs in a sandbox. This sandbox prevents your extension from making network requests or moving sensitive content outside the extension’s address space.

